# How to redirect .html extension to .com using htaccess in wordpress?(fixed by CBroe)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404, http-redirect

What I want to achieve is that:

**From the Structure:** http + .html

**To the structure:** https + .com

Below is example:
**From:** http://www.chiamhuiy.com/2022/07/fat-boys-food-review-burger-making-celine-chiam-singapore-lifestyle-beauty-and-travel-blogger-4.html/
**To:** https://www.chiamhuiy.com/2022/07/fat-boys-food-review-burger-making-celine-chiam-singapore-lifestyle-beauty-and-travel-blogger-4/
You can see that there is 404 error, unable to achieve the redirect.

I have installed SSl on cloudflare and I have tested from http to https .com version, it will auto redirect.
However, .html cannot redirect to non-html(only.com version)

Below is What I have followed and done but failed to achieve what I want:

**My original and existing .htaccess looks like**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#In here, please use the fourth attempt codes.It will work for redirection.
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**.html first attempt(failed)**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

**.html second attempt (failed)**

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

**.html third attempt(failed)**

```
RewriteRule (.+)\.html?$ http://example.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

**.html fourth attempt (failed)**

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*).(html)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Hopefully, some experts can kindly share a piece of .htaccess code which can get it done.

Comment: You need to show us _where_ you put your attempt(s), within the already existing rewrite setup.

Comment: Hi, thank your for your remind. Just add this line in original and existing setup
#Here is where I put below codes as an attempt without an #

Comment: That is too late at this point - WordPress has already rewritten every request that does not match onto an existing file or folder, to its own index.php at that point, and specified that this is the _last_ rewrite that should be performed in the current round. You need to do this _before_ the WP rewrites.

Comment: Thank you for answer. So is there any way to do this before WP rewrites by myself?

Comment: Yes, just change the _order_ ...

Comment: Ya, it works. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

#### Redirect .html Extension to .com in WordPress Using `.htaccess`

If you want to redirect URLs with a `.html` extension to URLs with a `.com` extension in WordPress, you can achieve this by modifying your `.htaccess` file. Here's how you can do it:

1. **Backup Your `.htaccess` File**:
   Before making any changes, create a backup of your existing `.htaccess` file.
2. **Edit Your `.htaccess` File**:
   Locate the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your WordPress installation. Edit the file using a text editor.
3. **Add the Following Code**:

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ http://www.example.com/$1.com [L,R=301]
   </IfModule>
   ```

Replace **http://www.example.com/** with your actual domain name.

This code snippet uses mod_rewrite to redirect URLs with the **.html** extension to the same URL with **.com** appended. The **[R=301]** flag indicates a permanent redirect, beneficial for SEO purposes.

1. **Save and Test:**
   Save your **.htaccess** file and test the redirection by accessing a URL with a **.html** extension in your browser. It should automatically redirect to the corresponding **.com** URL.

Ensure you clear your browser cache or use a different browser to test the redirection. Also, make sure there are no conflicting rules in your **.htaccess** file that might interfere with this redirection.